# Dynamically Cast Page.LoadControl in C#

Tags: c#, asp.net, .net

I'm writing some user controls for the first time and I'm wondering if there's a way I can clean up some of my code. (If you'd like more background on what I'm working on, see [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9234151/dynamic-page-rendering-in-aspx).)

I have a `BaseControl` class that, basically, parses some XML data and then, depending on what is contained in that data, calls the appropriate `UserControl` and sends the data on its way.  Here's an example:

```
public partial class BaseControl : User Control
{
    protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        ... //code that parses the data
        var renewalDef = effort.Attributes["renewal_def"].Value;
        var effortNumber = effort.Attributes["renewal_effort_number"].Value;
        if (effortNumber == "1")
        {
            var effortControl = (NAVLEffort1) Page.LoadControl("~/NAVLSeriesControls/NAVLEffort1.ascx");
            effortControl.transactionData = transaction; //'transaction' is a Hashtable object
            HtmlContent.Controls.Add(effortControl); //'HtmlContent' is a PlaceHolder control on BaseControl.ascx page
        }
        if (effortNumber == "2")
        {
            var effortControl = (NAVLEffort2) Page.LoadControl("~/NAVLSeriesControls/NAVLEffort2.ascx");
            effortControl.transactionData = transaction; //'transaction' is a Hashtable object
            HtmlContent.Controls.Add(effortControl); //'HtmlContent' is a PlaceHolder control on BaseControl.ascx page
        }
        if (effortNumber == "3")
        {
            var effortControl = (NAVLEffort3) Page.LoadControl("~/NAVLSeriesControls/NAVLEffort3.ascx");
            effortControl.transactionData = transaction; //'transaction' is a Hashtable object
            HtmlContent.Controls.Add(effortControl); //'HtmlContent' is a PlaceHolder control on BaseControl.ascx page
        }
        // and so on...
    }
}
```

This isn't the *actual* code I've written, it's just an example of where I could be headed.  What I'd like to do is something more like this:

```
...
var effortControlFileString = string.Format("~/NAVLSeriesControls/{0}Effort{1}.ascx", renewalDef, effortNumber);
var effortControl = (renewalDef + "Effort" + effortNumber) Page.LoadControl(effortControlFileString);
effortControl.transactionData = transaction;
HtmlContent.Controls.Add(effortControl)
...
```

Any ideas how I can clean this mess up?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### Interface

You could have all controls implement a common interface and cast to that.

```
public interface IMyInterface
{
    object TransactionData
    {
       get;
       set;
    }
}

Control effortControl = Page.LoadControl(path);
HtmlContent.Controls.Add(effortControl);

IMyInterface obj = (IMyInterface)effortControl;
obj.TransactionData = transaction;
```

See this [working example](http://www.coderun.com/ide/?w=0d7GFCmjsUq3TftYZqmdSg) in an online IDE.

### Base Class

You could also use an abstract base class and cast to that type with the same results. You will need to use a base class which inherits from `UserControl`. This would avoid having two object references (as in my example above) because it can be cast to `UserControl`.

The example above becomes:

```
MyCustomControlType c = (MyCustomControlType)Page.LoadControl(path);
HtmlContent.Controls.Add(c);
c.TransactionData = transaction;
```

If the logic for each control type is different, then you will probably need to cast to each specific type (basically a big if/else block) and deal with each control individually. In other words, if you need to perform different actions based on the type of the control, you will need logic that is type-aware.

For completeness sake I will mention that you could also use the [DLR](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd233052.aspx) but I would suggest against it. You would be giving up compile-time type safety and performance to reduce a little code.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. I tried the Interface approach, but I'm getting errors.  On the `Page.LoadControl` line (3rd to last) I'm getting the error `Cannot cast expression of type 'System.Web.UI.Control' to type 'IMyInterface'`. On the last line, the error is `Argument type 'BaseControl.IMyInterface' is not assignable to parameter type 'System.Web.UI.Control'`. Any idea what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: @spncrgr - my mistake; I misplaced the cast. I updated the example, added an additional example which may be simpler (base class), and created a sample project online for you.

Comment: Success! I had a bit of trouble implementing the interface, but the example you pointed me to helped me work it out. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

you can create an interface and add your control to html page.
ex:

```
private Control _contentControl;

_contentControl = Page.LoadControl("~/Administration/Projects/UserControls/" + controlName);
        ((IEditProjectControl)_contentControl).ProjectId = ProjectId;
        plhContent.Controls.Clear();
        plhContent.Controls.Add( _contentControl );
        _contentControl.ID = "ctlContent";
        Image2.Visible = ((IEditProjectControl)_contentControl).ShowSaveButton;
        SaveButton.Visible = ((IEditProjectControl)_contentControl).ShowSaveButton;
        ((IEditProjectControl)_contentControl).Initialize();
```